# Set for single instances of classes

Tags: java

I have a `Set` of objects and I don't want to allow to store there more than one instance of any class. Which solution is the best:

- check if there is an instance of given class in a set (doesn't seem to be efficient)
- implement `hashCode` to return constant and `equals` to return `o != null && o.getClass() == getClass()`
- make own implementation of `Set` (almost like first option)
- anything else? maybe there is already such a set?

Comment: I'm not sure your second option would work. Wouldn't you have to implement hashCode and equals for every single class in the java class hierachcy. Or are there only specific classes you want to store in your Set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `Map<Class<? extends T>, T>` for it.

---

**Example implementation:**

```
class SingleInstanceSet<T> {

    Map<Class<? extends T>, T> map = new HashMap<Class<? extends T>, T>();

    public boolean add(T o) {

        if (map.containsKey(o.getClass()))
            return false;

        map.put((Class<? extends T>) o.getClass(), o);
        return true;
    }

    public T get(Class<? extends T> klass) {
        return map.get(klass);
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassSet<Object> instances = new ClassSet<Object>();

    instances.add("hello");
    instances.add(1234);
    instances.add("will not be added");

    System.out.println(instances.map);
}
```

Outputs something like:

```
{class java.lang.String=hello, class java.lang.Integer=1234}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashMap. Before adding an object, get its class (using reflection) and check whether it is already a key in the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

You could <strike>invent</strike> implement a small wrapper class and store that instead of the instances:

```
 public class InstanceWrapper {
   private Object obj;
   public InstanceWrapper(Object obj) { this.obj = obj; }
   public Object getObject() { return obj; }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
     return this.getClass().equals(other.getClass());
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
     return this.getClass().hashCode());
   }
 }
```

As equality is defined via the Class instances, a set will only accept one instance of any class.

Answer (score 0):

Guava provides [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html), which is already checked for safety, tested, and the like.  It's like a `Map<Class<T>, T>`, but it deals with all the type system stuff already.